# How do I take 1 column of values and put some of those values in a new column based on a boolean flag column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Say I have the following 2 dimensional dataframe

```
+--------+-------------------+------------+
| Index, | Module/Line Item, | Is Module, |
+--------+-------------------+------------+
| 0,     | Module 1,         | True,      |
|--------|-------------------|------------|
| 1,     | Line Item 1,      | False,     |
|--------|-------------------|------------|
| 2,     | Line Item 2,      | False,     |
|--------|-------------------|------------|
| 3,     | Module 2,         | True,      |
|--------|-------------------|------------|
| 4,     | Line Item 1,      | False,     |
|--------|-------------------|------------|
| 5,     | Line Item 2,      | False      |
+--------+-------------------+------------+
```

And I want it to turn into this:

```
+----------+-------------+
| Module   | Line Item   |
+----------+-------------+
| Module 1 | Line Item 1 |
|          |-------------|
|          | Line Item 2 |
|----------|-------------|
| Module 2 | Line Item 1 |
|          |-------------|
|          | Line Item 2 |
+----------+-------------+
```

What would be the best way to accomplish that? I tried pivot_table and groupby but I couldn't get either to work the way that I wanted.
Note there are not a set number of Line Items between Modules, and no patterns in the names. The "Is Module" column is the only indicator of whether the value is a module and should be pivoted. All Line items that appear beneath the module until the next module should belong to that module when pivoted.

This is not answered by [How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe) because it never explains how to split a column into a hierarchy based on the values that are given in another column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) for replace `False` values by `Is Module` by forward filling, rename columns name and last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `loc` for filter also columns names:

```
df['Module'] = df['Module/Line Item'].where(df['Is Module']).ffill()
df = df.rename(columns={'Module/Line Item':'Line Item'})
df = df.loc[~df['Is Module'], ['Module','Line Item']]
print (df)
     Module    Line Item
1  Module 1  Line Item 1
2  Module 1  Line Item 2
4  Module 2  Line Item 1
5  Module 2  Line Item 2
```

If need also replace duplicated values by `Module` with empty values:

```
df['Module'] = df['Module'].mask(df['Module'].duplicated(), '')
print (df)
     Module    Line Item
1  Module 1  Line Item 1
2            Line Item 2
4  Module 2  Line Item 1
5            Line Item 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using `groupby`

```
df.groupby(df['Is Module'].cumsum())['Module/Line Item']\
.apply(lambda g: pd.DataFrame({'Module':g.iloc[0],
                               'Line Item': g.iloc[1:].values}))\
.set_index('Module')

            Line Item
Module  
Module 1    Line Item 1
            Line Item 2
Module 2    Line Item 1
            Line Item 2
```